# conditional sum sql query

Tags: mysql, sum

My table structure is following :

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_erp_invoice_lines` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `INVOICE_ID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `PRODUCT_ID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LINE_UNIT` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT 'KG' COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `LINE_PRICE` DECIMAL(7,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LINE_QUANTITY` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LINE_VAT` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '18',
    `LINE_MARK` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CREATEDON` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    `CREATEDBY` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `LASTUPDATEON` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
    `LASTUPDATEBY` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '1',
)
```

LINE_MARK is always `-1 or 1`

In this table there may be several records with same PRODUCT_IDs. And those records may have a LINE_MARK `-1 or 1`

Now I want to `SUM(LINE_PRICE*LINE_QUANTITY*LINE_MARK)` for the PRODUCT_IDs which has at least one `LINE_MARK=-1` in the table. If there isnt then records with this PRODUCT_ID will be excluded from SUM()

```
select SUM(LINE_PRICE*LINE_QUANTITY*LINE_MARK) from tbl_erp_invoice_lines 
where LINE_MARK=-1
```

doesn't work because in this case every record with LINE_MARK=1 will be excluded which I don't want

Thanks!

Comment: "CASE WHEN LINE_MARK=-1 THEN LINE_PRICE * LINE_QUANTITY * LINE_MARK ELSE 0"  seems like it may help here, I don't have an install to test against though. I'd try it within your SUM

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using *exists* to check the existence of any valid row:

```
select Sum(LINE_PRICE * LINE_QUANTITY * LINE_MARK) 
from tbl_erp_invoice_lines l
where exists (
  select 1 from tbl_erp_invoice_lines x
  where x.PRODUCT_ID = l.PRODUCT_ID and x.LINE_MARK = -1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that finds all the products that have at least one `LINE_MARK=-1` row.

```
SELECT SUM(LINE_PRICE*LINE_QUANTITY*LINE_MARK)
FROM tbl_erp_invoice_lines AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT product_id
    FROM tbl_erp_invoice_lines
    WHERE LINE_MARK = -1
) AS t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried to solve this question with the help of artificial intelligence. First, I consulted Bard. Despite many attempts, Bard was unable to find the correct answer. On the other hand, ChatGPT gave the correct result on its first attempt.

And here is the correct solution

```
SELECT SUM(il.LINE_PRICE * il.LINE_QUANTITY * il. LINE_MARK) as TOTAL
FROM tbl_erp_invoice_lines il
WHERE il.PRODUCT_ID IN (
    SELECT il2.PRODUCT_ID
    FROM tbl_erp_invoice_lines il2
    WHERE il2. LINE_MARK = -1
)
```

Comment: I would recommend the answer I posted using *exists* it is the preferred method over using *in*; in addition, ChatGPT answers are to be avoided, both on Stack Overflow by policy and in general, if you have no idea in the first place then it's only a matter of time before you use something *really* bad.